# Relationship between ROC (receiver operating characteristic) curve and cross-over error rate?

Tags: classification, roc, crossover-study

I do not understand this relationship.

According to wikipedia, the CER can easily be obtained from the ROC curve.

*Equal error rate or crossover error rate (EER or CER): the rate at which both acceptance and rejection errors are equal. The value of the EER can be easily obtained from the ROC curve. The EER is a quick way to compare the accuracy of devices with different ROC curves. In general, the device with the lowest EER is the most accurate.*

However, the ROC and CER curves are clearly very different:
ROC [image: ROC]

and CER:

[image: CER]

How is the Cross Over Error rate "easily obtained" from the ROC curve?  Or rather, what is the quantitative relationship between these?

It might be worth mentioning that my application is not for biometrics, but it *is* a binary classifier.  Thanks

Comment: Hi. I cannot believe your question still exists, for over five years and there is no answer. I have got the same problem. Have you found anything instructive on that? Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, not.  The question has only existed since July 10th of this year.  Please upvote to give it more attention!

Comment: I have got date wrong :p

Answer (score 3):

Type 1 error is the false positive rate (FPR, $\alpha$). Type 2 error is the false negative rate (FNR, $\beta$). On an ROC curve the y-axis is the true positive rate. However, that makes the y-axis 1-FNR or 1 minus the false negative rate. So we can relabel that axis the FNR by writing the numbers as descending in the y-axis values are increasing direction. We then have a plot of $\alpha$ decreasing on y versus $\beta$ increasing on x. That allows us to plot a line segment with intercept {0,0}, which is then the line of equality of $\alpha=\beta$, which is what you requested, as below,
[image]

Finally, the intersection of that new diagonal line segment with the example model curves given shows how well those models perform when $\alpha=\beta$. This makes sense when the *cost* of a false negative outcome is equal to the *cost* of a false positive outcome. Thus, using a graphic to digital interface, https://plotdigitizer.com/app, we find for the *great model* that $\alpha=\beta=0.02$, for the *good model* that $\alpha=\beta=0.17$ and for the *bad model* that $\alpha=\beta=0.36$. Note that all three areas under the ROC curves have discriminatory power, as those areas are all $>0.5$. Also, please note that $\alpha=\beta=0.5$ is only an approximation for an area of $0.5$ because the model shapes are irregular. Thus, the concept of what significance implies is not the same as it would be for a typical test of significance, as here *approximately* $\alpha=\beta<0.5$ is significant (from $\text{AUC}\approx 1-\alpha=1-\beta>0.5$).

If, on the other hand, the cost of a false negative is twice that of a false positive, the new line would become a curve, the shape of which is left as an exercise to the reader.

How this relates to the usual test of significance with $\alpha=0.05$ and $\beta<0.05$ is unclear, and exactly what the Wikipedia post for [crossover error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Crossover_error_rate) (CER) means beyond the bare bones statement that *A system with a lower CER value provides more accuracy than a system with a higher CER value* is also unclear because accuracy calculated without a cost accounting of FPR versus FNR outcomes is inappropriate. For those reasons; the not so obvious relationship to usual statistical testing, the lack of direct relationship to the AUC of ROC curves, and the difference between accuracy and weighted cost, unmodified CER should not be taken as having an unambiguous meaning.